# Why is it called "mode" in MAP estimation?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, bayes

When estimating parameters with MAP, why is it written that we are estimating the "mode"?
I thought it would be the mean of the posterior distribution?

Comment: MAP does not return an _estimate_ of the mode of the sampling distribution but _is_ the mode of the posterior distribution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [maximum a posteriori estimation (MAP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation), we use the maximum of the posterior distribution to derive point estimates of whatever we are interested in. The maximum of a distribution is also called its "mode" (assuming a unimodal distribution).

This is *not* the mean of the posterior (or any other) distribution. The difference is relevant when the posterior is asymmetric.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calculating the MAP estimate of the parameter, you assume posterior quantity to be of [unimodal distribution](http://www.statisticshowto.com/unimodal-distribution-2/) like normal distribution or chi-square distribution. And the mode of the unimodal distribution doesn't mean the most frequent value, it refers to the local maximum or the peak point. That's is why you call MAP as the mode of the distribution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to X'ian's comment.

Answer (score 0):

The *mode* of the posterior $\arg \max p(\theta|x)$ does not always coincide with the *mean* of the posterior $\int_{\Theta} \theta p(\theta|x) \mathrm{d}\theta$. It does in some cases, like a Gaussian posterior, but generally it does not. Depending on your field, the latter is called expected a-posteriori (EAP), or simply posterior expectation.